# Magento : Catalog Price Rule Date Not Working Properly

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, catalog-price-rules, date

I want to give some discounts for some products. Discount should start from a certain date, let's say 20/04/2017. This date is working fine if I use *special price field* in product management.

But when using **Catalog price rule**, this date is not working. I need to write 19/04/2017 in order for discount to work on 20/04/2017. What is wrong?

Comment: I actually think this is Magento standard behaviour. I tried this with a brand new installation on a different server. and it is the same issue.

Comment: +1 we are seeing te exact same thing; confirmed on M1.9.3.4 (same goes for end date: end by 30 JAN, then we have to set the end date to 29 JAN)

Answer (score 4):

I cant comment, you need to check some conditions :

1)cron jobs working or not by installing Aoe scheduler extension or some other way

2)check magento site timings and server timings both are same

Comment: servertime is correct. as I also described that the date in for special price field in product management is working properly.